# Deciphering instruments readout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit, instruments

CPU usage at ~50% / energy usage "Very high" in my sprite kit game.

I use tile sets to setup the levels. After the tile sets are in place I use clear, non-dynamic sprites with collision/contact bit masks for floors/walls/etc. I get a constant 60FPS, and my memory usage is only ~32MBs.

For animations as of now I have:

- 3 roving (forever) enemies which are not removed from the scene unless stepped on and killed
- 9 vertically moving platforms (up and down forever). Each platform uses an SKaction from game scene.sks and each also moves at different speeds / distances. These aren't ever removed from the scene.

I suspect my issue is related to the platforms, but I'm not sure since I'm having trouble deciphering the instruments readout from the CPU. Here is a screenshot of the readout at the point I think the issue is:

[image: Instruments screenshot]

Comment: Instruments is a large tool and it would be almost impossible to convey your problem in a SO question unless you had a very specific question about how to use it, which you do not.  By what you are showing here, you have a lot going on during your drawing phase, but that is only a guess.

Comment: @genericguy25 Do you have the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes selected for the call tree? Selecting those checkboxes makes it easier to find your code in the call tree view. You can access the call tree checkboxes by clicking the Call Tree button at the bottom of your screenshot. You can also try the Time Profiler instrument to find the slow spots in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips to both of you.

Comment: The energy gauge is not very nuanced. You can get a "very high" reading for an idle physical device with screen brightness on max and the radios in use. Screen brightness is clearly something you have no control over, radio usage or GPS you have some, but my point is you'll need to use detailed Instruments to try and isolate down to your specific code.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I thought the energy drain was only talking about the game specifically, not all phone functions including the game at once.