# Gauge acceptable CPU/GPU usage for different type of spritekit games

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, instruments

I've been working on a simple platformer for a few weeks now and for the first time today I ran my game using instruments to check out the timing profile. I was shocked to see CPU usage around ~40-50 percent and energy drain on very high. I started removing actions that ran forever, enemies, sprites, then I removed everything in my update, didSimulatephysics, and commented out the other once per frame update functions.

After all this my CPU usage was only down to about 35-45% and my energy drain was still very high.

I then came to the realization that I have no idea how low my CPU usage or energy drain should actually be (or even what to shoot for)

I know this is kind of a broad question, but does anyone have any idea what type of average CPU/energy usage spritekit I should shoot for? Obviously the lower the better, but what is acceptable?

EDIT: [CPU usage at ~50% / energy usage "Very high" in my sprite kit game. Need help deciphering instruments readout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569540/cpu-usage-at-50-energy-usage-very-high-in-my-sprite-kit-game-need-help-de?noredirect=1#comment78111478_45569540)

Comment: First of all, which device you use ? What is the number of draws and nodes on screen ? Do you remove off-screen nodes ?

Comment: I'm using a 6+. Nodes is ~80. the level is basically a large cave that the player explores. All nodes start on screen and aren't removed since they are non dynamic sprites that simply act as flooring and walls. I setup my levels on the scene editor. I don't remove nodes not in view because I'm not sure how to load only the sprites in the player view.

Comment: What is the draw count ? (view.showsDrawCount = true).

Comment: As I navigate the level it starts at 5 and then bounces around from 5-10 draws. I have all my textures in a sprite atlas and use two tile maps to layout my level. (Thanks for responding!)

Comment: That part seems fine...

Comment: Yea I dont see what the issue is. if you would please check the OP. I updated it with my previous post. It has a screenshot of my instruments readout and i drilled down to where i think the issue is but i cant really understand what it says